# What characters are allowed in the name of a rule in Drools?

Tags: character, drools, naming, punctuation

I haven't been able to find in Drools documentation, which characters (beyond alphabet letters) are allowed/disallowed in a rule name in Drools - does anyone know or have a reference?

The only relevant section of [Drools doc](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.49.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#drl-packages-con_drl-rules) I've found so far does not specify:

> Each rule must have a unique name within the rule package. If you use the same rule name more than once in any DRL file in the package, the rules fail to compile. Always enclose rule names with double quotation marks (rule "rule name") to prevent possible compilation errors, especially if you use spaces in rule names.

---

I think I have discovered, anecdotally, that some "grouping" characters do not work in rule names (seems rules named with can't be found or aren't included) - or at least, in *extension* rules (the extended rule seems to work with grouping chars, but not its extension; example below): The grouping chars include parentheses "()", square brackets "[]", and "curly braces" "{}".  Although less than & greater than "<>" work, so I'm so far replacing the former with the latter.

*Or are there escape chars for the problematic grouping chars?*

*Example*:

```
rule "(grouping chars, and commas, work here)"
when
    // conditions LHS
then
end

// removing parentheses, or replacing with < >,
// from below line works
rule "(grouping chars DON'T work here)"
extends "(grouping chars, and commas, work here)"
when
then
    // consequences RHS
```

---

I haven't discovered either way yet with all other characters (for example, other punctuation; except I have discovered commas "," work).  But it would be nice to know ahead of time what characters are allowed.

Comment: You should be able to find the antlr definitions describing the drl language on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically every identifier inside a string should work, but you might have empirically found some combination that is breaking the [grammar](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/f91c38c53dbc3f06d1e29dcdee91c2be7eb60bd3/drools-compiler/src/main/java/org/drools/compiler/lang/DRL6Parser.java#L1398) somehow.

Thanks for the investigation, I've filled a [Jira](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DROOLS-6035), please take a look at it